# Totally ramified extensions of p-adic fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-fields

Let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ denote the field of p-adic numbers. For a prime number $q$ ($\neq p$), does exist a totally ramified extension $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ with Galois group isomorphis to $\mathbb{Z}_q \times \mathbb{Z}_q$?

Comment: Yes if $q\nmid p-1$, otherwise no: $p\nmid [K:\Bbb{Q}]$ means that $K$ is a tamely ramified extension, thus $K\subset T=\bigcup_{p\nmid n}\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_n,p^{1/n})$, and $T\cap \Bbb{Q}_p^{ab}=\bigcup_{p\nmid n}\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_n,p^{1/(p-1)})$ (for $p$ odd)

Comment: I missed you said totally ramified, thus always no.

Comment: No, because the tame inertia group is cyclic.